# Add values to TableView columns from ObservableList<String> list

Tags: java, insert, tableview, tablecolumn

I have a problem regarding the process of inserting values to a TablewView from a list (Observable list).

I am getting the info from a GIS web service, and that service has over 3000 records in its attribute table with 10 columns. Each column has a different value.

I am extracting the column names from that service and create a list, and after I do the same with the values.

*Something like:*

columnNamesList : *["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"...];*

valuesList : *[
"record1Column1Value", "record1Column2Value","record1Column3Value",
"record2Column1Value", "record2Column2Value", "record2Column3Value",
"record3Column1Value", "record3Column2Value", "record3Column3Value"];* and so on.

When I am inserting the values into the TableView, all the values from the list are inserted into the first column, and after, everything repeats for every column in the table.

See picture attached. All the values from the first column should have been the first record.

[Click to see print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4ES5.png)

My question is, why are the values not inserted column by column, but as a bulk into all columns.

I would be grateful if someone finds the problem to why are the values inserted as specified

See code below:

```
private void addDataToTable(TableView tableView, String serviceUrl){
        // Setup the Service and the Query
        ServiceFeatureTable featureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable(serviceUrl);
        QueryParameters query = new QueryParameters();
        query.setWhereClause("1=1");

        ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> tableQueryResult = featureTable.queryFeaturesAsync(query, ServiceFeatureTable.QueryFeatureFields.LOAD_ALL);
        tableQueryResult.addDoneListener(() -> {
            //Return data after the query 
            try{

                ArrayList<String> flds = new ArrayList<>();
                ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                FeatureQueryResult result = tableQueryResult.get();

                int numerOfFields = result.getFields().size();
                // Add a tableColumn into the table for each field found in the service
                for(int i=0; i<numerOfFields; i++){
                    String fldName = result.getFields().get(i).getName();
                    System.out.println("Nume camp: " + fldName.toString());
                    flds.add(fldName);

                    TableColumn<String, String> tableColumn = new TableColumn(fldName);
                    tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue()));

                    //Add tableColumn with the specified name
                    tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumn);

                }

                Iterator<Feature> iterator = result.iterator();
                //while(iterator.hasNext()){
                //Getting only the first record from the data for test purpose
                for(int z= 0; z<1; z++){
                    Feature feature = iterator.next();
                    System.out.println(feature.getAttributes().values().getClass().getName());
                    for(int j=0; j<numerOfFields; j++){

                        //For each field found for that record, add the value into the DATA list
                        data.addAll(feature.getAttributes().get(flds.get(j)).toString());
                    }
                }
                // Add data list into the tableView
                tableView.setItems(data);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

**UPDATE !**
I found the solution at the following page: http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/19/dyanmic-tableview-data-from-database/

Comment: So, what's your question? Do you want our help in resolving this? If so, how can we help your without seeing the broken code? Post your code as a [mcve] - just the relevant code, in a runnable (verifiable) manner.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post by inserting the code. The question is basically why am I getting the values inserted in that manner... :) Thanks

Comment: I found a solution using the method at this page : [link](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/19/dyanmic-tableview-data-from-database/)